# Growing my mint plants and I need help

Tags: plant-care, mint

How do I know when my chocolate mint plant and cocktail mint plant is ready? Help please

Comment: Ready to pick/harvest?

Answer (score 3):

Mint is very hardy — invasive, even — and you can pick some almost as soon as it's a few inches tall.

A good rule-of-thumb is to pick gently until flower buds begin to form, then pinch them off and pick leaves more aggressively. The buds will have more flavour, and so you'll need less of them. Don't let it flower! You'll get the most yield if you "sexually frustrate" the plant by continually picking off the buds before they flower!

You can probably get away with picking a quarter of the leaves at a time, then letting it recover for a spell.